# How to remove duplicates rows from CSV file using Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, csv, npm, node-modules

I have a csb files with 2,000,000 entries. Some of rows are duplicated rows which I wanted to find and remove it.

Logic

The data will be like in the below format

column 1...column 2 ...column 2 ...column 4

XXX    ...123      ...abc      ...a

YYY     ...456      ...def      ...b

ZZZ     ...123      ...abc      ...c

ZZZ     ...123      ...abc      ...d

So, I wanted to find out duplicates without considering last column. So as per the above table, last 2 entries will be duplicate entry.

In these duplicates, I wanted to remove the first entry and retain the 2nd one.

Please suggest which method will better achieve this solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Please specify what you have tried first. This is not the place where you can ask your homework questions